# Placing two columns side by side with image and text

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone currently I have the following:

```css
.iconcontainer.first, .iconcontainer.second {
    display: inline-block;
}
.iconcontainer img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fullhome {
    background-color: #FEF1D9;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullhome">
    <div class='fulliconcontainer'>
        <div class='iconcontainer first'>
            <img class='homeicons1' src="http://localyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/local-seo-reviews-icon.png">
            <p>I want this under first image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='iconcontainer second'>
        <img class='homeicons1' src="http://www.pd4pic.com/images800_/flat-keyboard-theme-typing-icon-types.png">
        <p>I want this under second image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is put the content in `iconcontainer1` and `iconcontainer2` next to each other to create the effect of two columns. For some reason `iconcontainer2` falls to the bottom. Does anyone know how to fix this? I thought `inline-block` would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two elements with `inline` or `inline-block` will always have a space between them. You can float those two elements instead by doing `float: left`.

If you want to use `inline-block` make sure you remove `space` or `newline` to remove the space between them.

In your case you have to do this:

```
<div class='iconcontainer first'>
    <img class='homeicons1' src="http://localyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/local-seo-reviews-icon.png">
    <p>I want this under first image</p>
  </div><div class='iconcontainer second'>
  <img class='homeicons1' src="http://www.pd4pic.com/images800_/flat-keyboard-theme-typing-icon-types.png">
  <p>I want this under second image</p>
</div>
```

**Update:**

Didn't noticed that you put `50%` in `img` element which is wrong. You should put it on the containers which are `.iconcontainer.first, .iconcontainer.second`.

Your final css should look like this :

```
.iconcontainer.first, .iconcontainer.second{
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}

.iconcontainer img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fullhome{
  background-color: #FEF1D9;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqmj0cg5/)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `<div class='fulliconcontainer'>` get closed too early in the HTML, correct that to make the two `<div class='iconcontainer'>` as siblings.

`inline-block` also renders white space, there are [few ways](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) to avoid it, using the font size trick is so far the easiest.

```css
.fulliconcontainer {
    font-size: 0;
}
.iconcontainer.first, .iconcontainer.second {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
.iconcontainer img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fullhome {
    background-color: #FEF1D9;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullhome">
    <div class='fulliconcontainer'>
        <div class='iconcontainer first'>
            <img class='homeicons1' src="http://localyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/local-seo-reviews-icon.png" />
            <p>I want this under first image</p>
        </div>
        <div class='iconcontainer second'>
            <img class='homeicons1' src="http://www.pd4pic.com/images800_/flat-keyboard-theme-typing-icon-types.png" />
            <p>I want this under second image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can set them to `float` instead of inline block. Don't forget to [clear the float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

```css
.fulliconcontainer {
    overflow: auto;
}
.iconcontainer.first, .iconcontainer.second {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
.iconcontainer img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.fullhome {
    background-color: #FEF1D9;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullhome">
    <div class='fulliconcontainer'>
        <div class='iconcontainer first'>
            <img class='homeicons1' src="http://localyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/local-seo-reviews-icon.png" />
            <p>I want this under first image</p>
        </div>
        <div class='iconcontainer second'>
            <img class='homeicons1' src="http://www.pd4pic.com/images800_/flat-keyboard-theme-typing-icon-types.png" />
            <p>I want this under second image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```